# How to disable S.M.A.R.T. check for single drive?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I have external RAID array which do not support S.M.A.R.T. well and Ubuntu annoys me constantly with random warning about drive being bad, which it is not. I would like to disable S.M.A.R.T. test just for this external drive. How I can do that? (raid enclosure have its own health tests, so I should be good without smart.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by no means any kind of recommendation. But it is an answer.

Open the application "Palimpsest". It's installed by default, but usually called something else, although I'm not using English desktop. In Unity, you'll find it if you search for palimpsest, or you can press alt+f2 and type palimpsest.

Select your disk. At the bottom of the upper right column, you'll see something like "SMART-data" with a sub-label similar to "Show SMART-data and run self-tests". Click it. It will open another window. In that window, at the bottom-left, you can check a checkbox to not warn you if the drive fails.

Here are some screenshots for reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's what I need, thanx! Just for anybody else - it called "Disk Utility" and located in System > Administration for regular gnome desktop.